# Тире после слова

Tags: пунктуация, тире

Нужно ли тире после "приключений" здесь?

> Вместо приключений — боевик.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

После "вместо", конечно же, никакое тире не нужно.
А вот постановка тире после "приключений" зависит и от контекста, и от замысла автора (то есть от обозначения пауз).

**А.** Тире ставится при наличии ***паузы*** в так называемых эллиптических предложениях (самостоятельно употребляемых предложениях ***с отсутствующим сказуемым***):
*Влево, в углу, у дверей, на табурете — ведро воды для жаждущих* (Пом.); *За калиткой — третий плац, строевой, необыкновенной величины* (Купр.).

**Вместо приключений — боевик.**
А сегодня стал проверять кассу, глядь, а **вместо денег ― резаная бумага**. [М. А. Булгаков. Мастер и Маргарита, часть 1 (1929-1940)]
Я не могу простить императрице, я ненавижу Распутина, я ненавижу этих новых сознательных офицеров и солдат, я ненавижу революционного генерала Самойлова. **Вместо любви ― ненависть**. [П. Н. Краснов. От Двуглавого Орла к красному знамени (книга 1) (1922)]

**Б.** При отсутствии паузы тире в эллиптическом предложении не ставится:
*А в доме стук, ходьба…* (Гр.); *Вдруг передо мною рытвина глубокая* (Л.).

**Вместо приключений боевик.**
Уж как мне хотелось таких бус… Подсмотрела в «Юном технике» как делают бусы те, у которых **вместо денег журнал** «Юный техник», и сама сделала их из бумаги. [М. Б. Бару. Замок с музыкой // «Волга», 2013]
**Вместо любви приход-расходная книга** ― близости, помощи, измен, отчуждений, любовь не объекта, но своего чувства, согревание по рецепту доброго Царя Давида своего холода на чужом сердце. [И. Г. Эренбург. Необычайные похождения Хулио Хуренито (1921)]

[Тире в неполном предложении](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=91#pp91) (Розенталь)

Answer (score 0):

Нужно. Оно заменяет глагол. Например, "идёт" или "показали".